# value from one function to be returned in another function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
create or replace function sub_function()
returns text as $$
declare 
variable varchar(40);
begin
insert into tbl_admin (NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,LEVEL,AUTHENTICATION_KEY) values       ('karunya','karusuresh.s@gmail.com','password12',1,'');
variable=(select NAME from tbl_admin);
return variable;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


create or replace function base_function()
returns text as $$
declare
variable1 text;
begin
create table if not exists tbl_admin(ADMIN_ID serial primary  key, NAME varchar(40),EMAIL text,PASSWORD text, LEVEL text,AUTHENTICATION_KEY text);
variable1=(select sub_function());
return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

The sub function is correctly inserting but it is not returning the name. please give me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how variable assignment is done in PL/pgSQL.

This

> `variable=(select NAME from tbl_admin);`

is not going to work properly. You are selecting the **all** rows from the table but assign that to a single variable. But you only want a single name - I guess the name you have just inserted. You should do something like this instead:

```
insert into tbl_admin 
  (NAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD,LEVEL,AUTHENTICATION_KEY) 
values 
  ('karunya','karusuresh.s@gmail.com','password12',1,'')
returning name into variable;

return variable;
```

This assignment is also wrong:

> `variable1=(select sub_function());`

All you need is:

```
variable1 := sub_function();
```

If you *really* want to use a select there, you need to use `into`:

```
select sub_function()
  into variable;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a344c/1

Comment: This is not working.. Wat i need is nested function. If it is not possible what is the procedure for calling a sub function in a base function.

Comment: @KarunyaSuresh "*what is the procedure for calling a sub function in a base function*" - I showed you two different ways of doing that. ""not working*" is not an acceptable error description

Comment: ERROR:  function sub_function() does not exist
LINE 1: select sub_function()
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  select sub_function()
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function base_function() line 6 at SQL statement

Comment: Then you apparently have not created a function named `sub_function()`. See the example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a344c/1